# can't see anything under Visual C# template inside visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I installed C# and business intelligence inside visual studio 2010 and now I'm able to access/create BI projects but can't findout anything under Visual C# template "no item found"

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio project creation form -> choose Visual C# and choose *Installed Templates*.

You see *no item found* cause most probably you have selected *Online Templates*.